# Polynomials with many roots(mod 9)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove: If a is any integer and the polynomial f (x) = x^2+ax + 1 factors (poly mod 9), then there are three distinct non-negative integers y less than 9 such that f (y) ≡ 0 (mod 9).

I don't know how to solve this problem. I don't know how to start.

Comment: When you are stuck on a problem, one tactic is to try to solve a particular instance.  The case $a=2$ looks like it would be especially simple to solve (and thus provide a check on the claim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: There are three ways you can have a product $ab$ divisible by $9$:

1. $9$ divides $a$.
2. $9$ divides $b$.
3. $3$ divides both $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a roadmap:

- If $x-u$ is a factor of $f(x)$, then $f(u)=0$.
- If $f(u)=0$, then $u \equiv a \bmod 3$.
- If $f(u)=0$, then $f(u+3)=0$.

Therefore, if $f(x)$ factors mod $9$, then its roots are $a$, $a+3$, $a+6$ mod $9$.

Comment: It would help to provide some intuition behind the method.

Comment: @BillDubuque, I started with a hunch for the last condition and worked backwards to the second condition. Or you could just start with $f(x)=0 \bmod 3$, which is natural.